# Linking tables in a Database

Tags: sql-server, database

Im currently trying to link tables and having a few problems, The tables are part of an ordering process in which users can add a customer to the system, place an order, update stock details and also when the order has been placed the stock details will also be updated.

I have four main tables - User, Customer, Order Details and Stock details.

I have it in my head that One user can add many customers, One user can add many orders and one user can add/update many stock details. When i do the tables out in access Im not sure how I link the relationships within the four main tables correctly

Comment: What database engine are you using? What code have you written to do such tasks you have in your head?

Comment: SQL server and im creating a visual basic web application but haven't started yet, trying to get the table design sorted first

Comment: Is it also true that -- One customer could have many orders and one order could have many stock details?  You may have more relationships than just Users to the other three tables.

Comment: Errrr, haven't you just described Microsoft own sample SQL Server database, Northwind ?  Have a look at that.

Comment: What do you mean "Do the tables out in access" and what do you mean by "how I link the relationships"? Are you asking about how to set up the foreign key relationships, or just about the basic schema for the tables that you want to create?